# Hadoop, hive -> get list of sql being run against the cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

So we have a group of people hitting our cluster and would like to monitor every SQL statement being run via hive/odbc. The job history server web page will give me part of the SQL but not everything. Is there a way to retrieve the full SQL of commands being run? Could be via web GUI or command line. I want to monitor for inefficient queries and send out warnings to developers.

Cluster is 10 node MapR cluster running Mapr 5.0 in yarn mode

Comment: Hue provides the ability to store Hive queries that are ran directly through Hue

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to track queries that are run via ODBC

Comment: ODBC/JDBC remotely? Wouldn't the client hold that? Why would the hadoop tools track that?

Comment: Well the request comes into Hadoop and hive processes the sql and turns it into a job. So it would have the SQL and should be able to log it. Why track it? Any good database we should be able to get a log of sql statements executed against it so we can see what is being run.

Comment: I mean, sure you can use Apache Ranger to perform audits on your system, but 1) I don't know about MapR 2) Who said Hive was a "good database"? :)

Comment: Yes, well, good point. It was written by Facebook. The only other app of theirs I use, the android Facebook app, is pretty buggy. I found the solution, I was looking in the wrong log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. SSH into the machine running hiveserver2 and execute the command below. Replace  with the user you are interested in (or * if you want them all) and replace hive-0.13 with the version of hive you are using.

`cat /opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.13/logs/<user>/hive.log | grep "Starting command"`

EDIT: in the year since I wrote this is appears it has changed to:

`cat /opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/logs/<user>/hive.log | grep "Executing command"`

EDIT Take 2. The above doesn't deal with multi-line sql and shows only the first line. For many of the queries it was simply showing "SELECT" and nothing more. The below solves the issue. I had a nice sed solution but it didn't work with `tail -f` for some reason, so Perl it is. Unusual for Perl but it's actually more readable than the sed solution.

`cat /opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.3/logs/<user>/hive.log | perl -ne 's/\r\n/ /g; print;' | grep "Executing command"`

Comment: Anyone know of any tools that will put a GUI and extra features on top of this?